# python -- trying to change the contents of a file

Tags: python

i have a file named "hello.txt" which has the content "Hello,there!".
I want to remove the "," and "!" and then print the new content.

With the code i made ,the program runs without errors but ,it erases all the contents and leaves an empty file.

```
def myfunc(filename):
filename=open('hello.txt','r')  
lines=filename.readlines()
filename.close()
filename=open('hello.txt','w')
for line in lines:
     for punc in ".!":
        line=line.replace(punc,"")
filename.close()


myfunc("hello")
```

Please,don't use high level commands.
Thanks!

Comment: Between `open( 'w')` and `close` you don't actually write into the file...

Comment: Being a high-level programming language, doesn't most of Python somehow consist of "high-level commands"?

Comment: by the way, the content of the function argument `filename` is overridden immediately in the first line of the function body.

Comment: @Sven Marnach:Ok, you are right but this comes in time.Right now,i use simple commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should print the modified content line by line, not only at the end.

```
for line in lines:
    for punc in ",!":

        # note that we're assigning to line again
        # because we're executing this once for
        # each character
        line=line.replace(punc,"")

    # write the transformed line back to the file once ALL characters are replaced
    #
    # note that line still contains the newline character at the end

    # python 3
    # print(line,end="")

    # python 2.x
    print >> filename, line,

    # python 2.x alternative
    # filename.write(line)
```

By the way, naming a file **handle** `filename` is confusing.

Comment: 1) The "file=filename" inside the print statement gives me a syntax error.  2) Now,the programs prints the desired result but the file is overriden and its blank.How can i have my new file(with the changes i did) in order to be able to  work on that.

Comment: Ok,this works now,but if i don't want to print the results and just keep the changes ,i tried to remove the "print >> filename,line," but now the file overrides and becomes blank again!

Comment: do `print line,` and do **NOT** open the file for writing (and don't close it the second time)

Comment: This prints ok the result in the screen but again the file becomes blank.I don't open the file again.

Comment: if you don't open the file in 'w' (or '+') mode, it can't be written to. Is it still empty from previous attempts ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3698/discussion-between-andre-holzner-and-george)

Answer (score 1):

You're changing lines in your program but not writing to the file. After making changes in lines, try `filename.writelines(lines)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex module. It's easy to make substitutions:

```
import re
out = re.sub('[\.!]', '', open(filename).read())
open(filename, 'w').write(out)
```